# Google People API Javascript - Store GivenName as Variable

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-people-api

I'm running into an issue with storing a Google API call as a variable. I believe it has to do with the fact the variable is called in a promise function, which I understand does not pass onto the global variable once executed. The result of the current code is 'null', which is the initial value of the variable.

I've removed much of the code to show the necessary excerpt:

```
var MyApp {
   name: null
};

function makeApiCall() {
     gapi.client.people.people.get({
       'resourceName': 'people/me',
       'requestMask.includeField': 'person.names'
     }).then(
       function(resp) {
       MyApp.name = resp.result.names[0].givenName;
       return MyApp.name;
     });
}

function getIP(json) {
    makeApiCall();          
    var person = MyApp.name;
    document.write(person);
}
```

Basically, I'd like the value of MyApp.name (global variable created earlier in the script) to change from 'null' to the API response so that the value printed in getIP(json) is givenName instead of null, which is my current output.

In other words, when I reference MyApp.name in the getIP(json) function, it should be referencing 'resp.result.names[0].givenName' instead of 'null'.

I've searched for a while on this topic but haven't had any success beyond knowing what does not work.

Comment: as your calls are async it depends when you are calling *getIP*, try calling getIP inside the response handler of the people request response

Comment: Yes, thank you - @youkouleley had a similar resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing this:

```
makeApiCall();          
var person = MyApp.name;
document.write(person);
```

You are telling Javascript to enqueue the Google API call, then immediately use the result before waiting for the request to complete.

Also, you should not use `document.write` because it will replace the whole document with the content of your variable since it will be called after the document has been rendered.

Try this instead:

```
gapi.client.people.people.get({
  'resourceName': 'people/me',
   'requestMask.includeField': 'person.names'
}).then(
  function(resp) {
    MyApp.name = resp.result.names[0].givenName;
    //Use MyApp.name here and don't use document.write
  });
```

Comment: Brilliant - your response worked. I should've thought to move the makeApiCall script to the getIP function since I'm calling its output there anyway. Thank you very much.